# Trying to append quotes to each item in list.

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to create a script that will take each line in my text file which includes one rule name in each of them. The first script I created worked (finished) but would delete everything in the file. I have been googling for past hour or so trying to take examples and apply them on my own but keep failing. The current script is as follows.

```
with open('TDAppendlist.txt', 'w') as file:
    for line in file:
        s = ('""')
        seq = (file)
        s.join(seq)

with open('TDAppendlist.txt') as file:
    line = file.readlines()
    for line in file:
        line.join('"' + line + '"')
```

Neither of them are working. Could someone please point me in the correct direction? Thank you all for reading.

Comment: Your first sentence is a little confusing. Can you show us some example input and output? Are you trying to modify the same file that you are reading?

Comment: Are you trying to write back to the file or print to screen?

Comment: You're not doing anything with `line` in the first part. Instead, you assign `seq` to `file` (unnecessary parentheses), then join that. Which feels kind of awkward, joining a file pointer with a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we'll read all the lines of the file into a list, then we can change them, and finally write them back to the file.

```
with open('TDAppendlist.txt') as file:
    lines = list(file)

with open('TDAppendlist.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(['"{}"'.format(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in lines]))
```

That last line can be written out to be more clear

```
lines = (line.rstrip('\n') for line in lines)
lines = ('"{}"'.format(line) for line in lines)
lines = '\n'.join(lines)
file.write(lines)
```

Answer (score 2):

This produces an output file `TDAppendlist_out` that is just like the input, but with quotes surrounding the lines:

```
with open('TDAppendlist.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('TDAppendlist_out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
        for line in f:
            f_out.write('\"{}\"'.format(line))
```

This keeps the input file intact as is should you need it later, and avoids putting everything in the input file into memory all at once.

Comment: There is no need for the backslashes. But the line breaks should _not_ be stripped.

Comment: No need to `.close()` files if you use `with`.